# How to pass messages from one class to another through NSNotification

Tags: iphone, ios, nsnotifications

Ha-ii ,am doing an in-app purchase in my application,i need to disable a button when the in-app content purchase is success,so i put the NSuserdefault to my code to identify weather its success or not,but NSUserDefault works only when i refresh the page,i didnt get the button enabled when the content success message is come ,i get enabled when i go back to another page and came back,my need is to pass instance message to the viewcontroller through notification.my code is

```
- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions {
    for(SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions) {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchasing:
                // Item is still in the process of being purchased
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                // Item was successfully purchased!

                // --- UNLOCK FEATURE OR DOWNLOAD CONTENT HERE ---
                // The purchased item ID is accessible via 
                // transaction.payment.productIdentifier

                // After customer has successfully received purchased content,
                // remove the finished transaction from the payment queue.
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Transsucess"];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                // Verified that user has already paid for this item.
                // Ideal for restoring item across all devices of this customer.

                // --- UNLOCK FEATURE OR DOWNLOAD CONTENT HERE ---
                // The purchased item ID is accessible via 
                // transaction.payment.productIdentifier

                // After customer has restored purchased content on this device,
                // remove the finished transaction from the payment queue.
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                // Purchase was either cancelled by user or an error occurred.

                if (transaction.error.code != SKErrorPaymentCancelled) {
                    // A transaction error occurred, so notify user.
                [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"Transsucess"];
                }
                // Finished transactions should be removed from the payment queue.
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: 

transaction];
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

in my anothervierwcontroller i want to pass the Notification value insted of Nsuserdefault value.
How to do this.please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your first view `vieDidLoad` add the line ..

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ContentPurchased) name:@"Purchased" object:nil];
```

**( do remove the observer in dealloc)**

then when you have successful purchase in your question code..
Post the notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Purchased"  object:nil userInfo:nil];
```

**You can pass an object**..but i believe you should store the purchase transaction detail in `NSUserdefautls`..since it will be needed in the next runs of the app..

When you **post** the **notification** `ContentPurchased` method is called in first view ( you have to add that in the view controller)

Comment: so i have to put  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Purchased"  object:nil userInfo:nil]; in 
 case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased: right?? then add [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ContentPurchased) name:@"Purchased" object:nil];
this in my viewcontroller right?these are two seperate classes

Comment: yes..two separate classes and  `[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(ContentPurchased) name:@"Purchased" object:nil];` is to be done first.. otherwise the method won't be called even if you post the notification..